# Link of react is not directing to a new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-router

I am making an ecommerce website. If I click a product, the product full description will be displayed in a new page called detailPage and there will be similar product fetched from the API at the bottom of the detailPage. It is working fine till here. But if I click any of the similar product, I want the similar product to be displayed in the detailPage. How can I make it work?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import useFetch from '../../Component/UseFetch/useFetch'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import './detailPage.css'

const DetailPage = () => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState([])
  const [mainImg, setMainImg] = useState('')
  const [sameProduct, setSameProduct] = useState([])
  const { loading, products } = useFetch('https://dummyjson.com/products')
  const { id } = useParams()


  useEffect(()=>{
    const product = products.find(product => product.id === Number(id))
    if(product){
      setItem(product)
      setMainImg(product.thumbnail)
    }
  },[products])



  useEffect(()=>{
    const allProduct = products.filter(product => product.category === item.category)
    setSameProduct(allProduct)
  }, [item, products])


  return (
    loading ? <div style={{
      width: '100vw',
      height: '100vh',
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      fontSize: '10vw'
    }}>Loading...</div> :
    <div>
       <div>
           <h1 className='product-headline'>Product Detail</h1>
       </div>
      <div className='product-box'>
         <div>
            {
              products && item && (
                <div style={{height: '320px'}}>
                   <img className='main-image' src={mainImg} />
                </div>
              )
            }
            <div className='short-img-box'>
            {
            products && item && item.images && item.images.map((image, id)=>{
              return <img className='short-img' key={id} src={image} onClick={()=> setMainImg(image) }/>
            })
            }
            </div>

         </div>
         <div>
          {
            products && item && item.price && !isNaN(item.price) && (
              <div>
                <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                <div>
                   <span>Rating: {item.rating}</span>
                   <span>Available Stock: {item.stock}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <span>{parseInt(item.price + item.price / 100 * 25)}</span><br></br>
                  <span>{item.price}</span>
                </div>
                <p>{item.description}</p>
              </div>
            )
          }
                   <button>Add to cart</button>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Review section</h1>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1 className='product-headline'>Similar Products</h1>
            <div className='products'>
                {
                    sameProduct.map((product)=>{
                      const {id, title, description, category, price, thumbnail, images, rating, stock} = product
                      return (
                            <div key={id} className='product'>
                                <Link to={`/detailpage/${id}`}><img src={thumbnail} /></Link>
                                <div className='product-details'>
                                  <Link className='title' to={`/detailpage/${id}`}><h3>{title}</h3></Link>
                                  <div className='price-rating'>
                                      <p>${price}</p>
                                      <p>Rating: {rating}/5</p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <button className='add-cart'>ADD TO CART</button>
                                <span className='product-stock'>Stock: {stock}</span>
                            </div>
                      )     
                    })
                }
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DetailPage
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that your only problem is that `id` is not included in your useEffect's dependency array. Can you confirm that that the url is updated to the new product id when you click the similar product?

In that case, all you should do is include the id in the dependency array like this to make the useEffect re-run when the id in the URL is changed:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const product = products.find(product => product.id === Number(id))
    if(product){
      setItem(product)
      setMainImg(product.thumbnail)
    }
  },[products, id])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution for this should be something like this (not find product in array of product, but fetch single product in single request (for details page):

You will add `useEffect` hook to handle, when `id` of product changed in URL.

```
    useEffect(()=> {
      // i change name of the function, beacuse it's impossible to use hooks inside callbacks
      const {loading, poduct} =  someFetchFunction('https://dummyjson.com/products');
      // save your data in `useReducer` hook (but it's up to you)
    }, [id]);
```

So right now when you change url on this page, this useEffect hook will trigger and get current product

---

You also have a way to change the `useFetch` hook, and move `useEffect` to this hook, so when something changes it will trigger a request, but from my perspective of view my first variant is better